# Upload file via WCF webHttpBinding using ComplexType argument

Tags: c#

I would like to ask for help.
Consider having following class:

```
public class UploadRequest{
    public byte[] Data{get;set;}

    public string Filename{get;set;}
}
```

and WCF method

```
UploadFile(UploadRequest request);
```

My config is:

```
<service name="WCF.Messenger" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
  <endpoint                 binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF.Interfaces.IMessenger" bindingConfiguration="soapBinding"/>
  <endpoint address="json"  binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="WCF.Interfaces.IMessenger" bindingConfiguration="jsonBinding"/>
  <endpoint address="mex"   binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
```

Can I somehow call this method via HTTP Web request?

Thanks for any replies

Answer (score -1):

if you want to call this method via http web request you have to use WCF REST Service

please look at this: [WCF Rest Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)

Comment: So if i get it correctly, you are suggesting to create a URL template and send the rest of the data (apart from byte[]) via GET parameters?